# I did a simple jquery slideshow - I want to toggle to one specific image by clicking thumbnail image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="slider_b">
  <img src="img/frame_wood_back_460_380.jpg">
  <img src="img/01_french_train_480_360.jpg">
  <img src="img/05_cherries_480_360.jpg">
  <img src="img/06_wheat_480_360.jpg">
  <img src="img/10_renault_480_360.jpg">
</div>
<div id="button"><img src="img/06_wheat_480_360.jpg" width="48px" height="auto"></div>

<script>
setInterval("switchit()", 3000);

$('.slider_b img:gt(0)').hide();

function switchit() {
$('.slider_b img:first-child').fadeOut(0).next('img').fadeIn(2000).end().appendTo('.slider_b');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider_box img{
     position:relative;
     top:0px;
    left: 0px; }
.slider_box {
    position:absolute;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px; }
#button {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 500px;}
```

The slideshow works - I just could not figure out how to switch the slideshow to one of the images by clicking a thumbnail button (id=button) - the slideshow should continue then in the regular circle order.

Comment: Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try making a relation between the slide and its thumbnail to fetch the respective slide, e.g. by using attibutes pairs, like `data-slide="slide1"` for the thumbnail and `id="slide1"` for the actual slide
2. on thumbnail click, adjust the current slide to the respective one and continue auto animation from this point

Point one is just one solution, it's the creativity part ;) You could come up with something else, like e.g. using thumbnails and slides indexes, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [data attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) to your `<img>` elements, and append the button with the first child `<img>`element to carry over that data attribute. e.g:

```
<img src="" data-slide="1">
```

And for the append

```
var thumbnail = $("div.slider_b").find("img:first");
$("#button > img").replaceWith(thumbnail);
```

Once this is done, make it so that

```
("#button").on(click, function() {
    var moveTo = $(this).find("img").data(slide);
    var item = $("div.slider_b").find("[data-slide='" + moveTo + "']"
    $("div.slider_b).prepend(item);
```

}

I'm not 100% right with the jQuery, but I believe I'm on the right lines. A bit more exploration down this route will get you to where you need to be.